# Як правильно нема чи немає?

Tags: граматика

Я часто  заплутуюсь,  як граматично правильно писати **'нема'** чи **'немає'** ?

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Запитання, які не демонструють спроби автора самостійно відповісти на нього, змушують інших «вгадувати», чого саме хоче автор, і тому заважають надавати точні відповіді. Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour](https://goo.gl/XbjRge), [How to Ask](https://goo.gl/KuCfff) а також [«Якими мають бути гарні запитання і відповіді»](https://goo.gl/wnuKFr). Щоб виправити запитання, натисніть edit у лівому нижньому куті під запитанням. Ще раз ласкаво просимо і дякуємо, що приєдналися до спільноти!

Answer (score 5):

Ось що з цього приводу каже професор [Пономарів](https://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/mobile/blogs/2013/11/131118_ponomariv_blog2_ko.shtml):

> На підставі словників можна зробити висновок, що ц**і присудкові слова
>   цілком взаємозамінні**, тотожні. Хіба що у швидшому темпі мовлення
>   вживаємо нема, у повільнішому – немає.
>
> Порівняймо: "Де нема святої волі, не буде там добра ніколи". (Тарас
>   Шевченко).
>
> "Немає там ні горя, ні зітхання". (Леся Українка).
>
> **В офіційному мовленні частіше використовують немає**. Конструкціями з нема, немає не потрібно зловживати. Там, де росіяни кажуть: "У меня
>   нет времени (нет желания
>   , нет настроения) ", ми кажемо: "Я не маю часу (не маю бажання, не маю
>   настрою)".

Також бачимо, що і [Словопедія](http://slovopedia.org.ua/32/53405/31575.html) і [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/nema) вказують на те, що ці слова є тотожні. Цікаву думку також зустрів на форумі [Словника](http://forum.slovnyk.ua/lofiversion/index.php?t22.html):

> Я б сказав так - таку скорочену форму дієслів теперішнього часу не
>   можна вживати в офіційній мові (**про слово "нема"**), бо її не зафіксовано чинним
>   правописом. Одначе як така вона є в українській мові, тому було б
>   добре, якби програма видавала до неї «м'яке» попередження, щось на
>   кшталт «рідке», «не рекомендоване»… Такі форми слід вжівати лише
>   зрідка, уникаючи їх зовсім у документах, дикторській мові на
>   телебаченні та радіо, та програмних інтерфейсах.
>
> Коротку синтетичну форму дієслів у майбутньому часі «писатимем»,
>   «прийматимем» занотовано в правописі як рідку, тому вона є прийнятною,
>   але стилістично їй не слід надавати переваги перед повною формою
>   «писатимемо», «прийматимемо».

Comment: Професор Пономарьов? Справді?

Comment: @P.Vowk, ну, він, здається, професор кафедри мови та стилістики Інституту журналістики Київського національного університету імені Тараса Шевченка. (Хоча прізвище офіційно Пономар_і_в.) (З думкою про доречність якогось (хоч і м'якого) попередження для слова _нема_ незгоден — ані теоретично (це давно вже не дієслово), ані практично (де-факто вживається не рідше за _немає_).)

Comment: @Sasha я лише про те, що він Пономарів.

Comment: Вибачте, очевидно мій телефон виправив Пономарів на Пономарьов, а я цього не помітив. Вже виправив.